# Updating variable of state and calling in react state?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using Steps from antD and facing problem in updating the steps w.r.t. the props changed.

```
 import Step1 from './step1.js'
  import Step2 from './step2.js'
  import {Steps} from 'antD'
  state={ 
          list:[] 
          step: [
           {
            title : "first"
            content : this.step1()
           } 
           {
            title : "Second"
            content : <Step2 list={this.list}/>
           } 
         ]
       }



step1=()=>{
return (
<Step1/>
)
}
 render(){
<div >
        <Steps current={current}>
          {this.state.step.map((item) => (
            <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
          ))}
        </Steps>
        <div >{this.state.step[current].content}</div>
        <div>
          {current < this.state.step.length - 1 && (
            <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.next()}>
              Next
            </Button>
          )}
          {current === this.state.step.length - 1 && (
            <Button
              type="primary"
              onClick={() => message.success("Processing complete!")}
            >
              Done
            </Button>
          )}
          {current > 0 && (
            <Button onClick={() => 
                this.prev()}>
              Previous
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
```

}

`this.state.list` updates every time a a function `f` triggers, but list in `Step2` doesn't updates. It's always null that passes.

EDIT : How do I access `step1()` inside state. `this` will refer state inside state.

This is my complete code..

Comment: I believe that the content would be created and `this.list` would resolve when  you create the state. So your step2 would always have the initial value. Also, wouldn't it be `this.state.list` in step2 anyway?

Comment: @ZacharyHaber this will refer to state in this case, that's why this.list

Answer (score 0):

Don't put React elements into state - doing so will frequently break things, especially if they take props that you want to change across renders.

Instead, so that React can update the props of the sub-components naturally, declare and pass down the sub-components inside the render method, so that whenever the state updates, the render method can be called again with the *new* props being passed down.

For example, rather than:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.step[1].content}
    </div>
  )
}
```

do

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Step2 list={this.list} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: how to access a function inside state? "this" will call state ? editing the question

Comment: Don't - state should usually be *data only*, rather than functions that depend on a calling context. Feel free to invoke functions in `render()` or elsewhere, but don't store functions in state.

Comment: Can you please once check my code. I'm not getting how to proceed in this . Looks like I'm wrong somewhere